# Removing square brackets from string including text inside the brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to remove all square brackets from a string including the text inside the opening and closing brackets. It shouldn't delete unclosed text.

- Example1: `Hell[o] [W[orl]d[!!` should be `Hell d!!`
- Example2: `Hell[]o] [W[orl]d[!!]` should be `Hell d`

Here's my code that seems to work: (EDIT: it doesn't work in some cases, see below)

```
let text = "Hell[o] [W[orl]d[!!";
let newText = "";
let buf = "";
let isOpened = false;
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  const char = text.charAt(i);
  if (char === "[") {
    isOpened = true;
  }
  else if (char === "]") {
    buf = "";
    isOpened = false;
  }
  else {
    if (isOpened) {
      buf += char;
    }
    else {
      newText += char;
    }
  }
}
newText += buf;

console.log(newText);
```

Result: `Hell d!!`

I would like to ask if there's a simpler solution than this.
Ideally, I would like to avoid copying the whole `text` to `newText` for better performance.

EDIT: I just found out my code doesn't work correctly with "Hell[]o] [W[orl]d[!!". It returns `Hello d!!` but it should be `Hell d!!`. How can I fix this?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see a series of example inputs/outputs. Btw, this looks like an ideal scenario for regular expressions!

Comment: I think that `Hell[]o] [W[orl]d[!!` returning `Hello d!!` is expected behavior - the `o` isn't completely wrapped in brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to accomplish this. The regex `/(?:\[.*?\]|[\[\]])/g` will work (by searching for both paired brackets with text inside and unpaired brackets)

```js
function stripBrackets(text) {
  return text.replace(/(?:\[.*?\]|[\[\]])/g, "")
}
console.log(stripBrackets("Hell[o] [W[orl]d[!!"));
console.log(stripBrackets("Hell[]o] [W[orl]d[!!]"));
```